# Delete Columns in Google Sheets for Multiple Tabs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a script that will delete the same number of columns for every tab in my sheet except for 2 tabs.  Very new to scripts, so I haven't gotten very far.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide your current script?

Answer (score 0):

#### Delete Columns in Sheets except for 2 sheets

```
function myfunk(col = 1, num = 1) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const excl = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2'];
  ss.getSheets().filter(s => !~excl.indexOf(s.getName())).forEach(sh => sh.deleteColumns(col, num));
}
```